# Minification folder and subfolders content

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, minimize

Can I minimized and is it useful when the UI is completely in Javascript (ExtJS) ?

How can I minimized, a folder and all subfolders (both with .js files) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize your Code using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) by providing a list of source files. UglifyJS has an option to minimize variables within different files.

```
var result = UglifyJS.minify([ "file1.js", "file2.js", "file3.js" ]);
console.log(result.code);
```

You can use `require('fs')` and write a short `node.js` script to load all js files in your directory and all subdirectories in an array and pass it to `UglifyJS.minify`

Minimization makes sense in most cases since it shortens the loading time of your scripts and hides the functionality and readability .

Answer (score -1):

Copied from ==> [How to form the folder structured tree in EXTJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339192/how-to-form-the-folder-structured-tree-in-extjs)

Below link may help you

[How to form the folder structured tree in EXTJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339192/how-to-form-the-folder-structured-tree-in-extjs)

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    // shorthand
    var Tree = Ext.tree;

    var tree = new Tree.TreePanel({
        useArrows: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        animate: true,
        enableDD: true,
        containerScroll: true,
        border: false,
        // auto create TreeLoader
        dataUrl: 'get-nodes.php',

        root: {
            nodeType: 'async',
            text: 'Ext JS',
            draggable: false,
            id: 'src'
        }
    });

    // render the tree
    tree.render('tree-div');
    tree.getRootNode().expand();
});
```

Demo Link also available at there
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/reorder.html